# UE4 FAssetRegistryModule macro for Standalone

Tags: unreal-engine4

This command (FAssetRegistryModule::AssetCreated) although it works well when used in "Selected Viewport", it crashes in Standalone mode. Which is the macro for not executing both in PIE and Standalone ?

```
#if WITH_EDITOR
     FAssetRegistryModule::AssetCreated(DynMaterial);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for executing commands in "Selected Viewport" and "Standalone" when in Editor.

```
if (GetWorld()->WorldType == EWorldType::PIE)
{
    FAssetRegistryModule::AssetCreated(DynMaterial);
}
```